# jQuery fadeIn issue or alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sending a post request to a file and putting that in the id='balance' but I want it to flicker or fadeIn so that the user knows that it's being updated live.  I tried adding a fadeIn() but it's not doing what I'm trying to do.  Am I doing it wrong or is there a better way?  Code below.

```
var balance_update = setInterval(function() {
    $.post('./requests/balance.php', function(balance) {
        $('#balance').html(balance).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to hide it first, since `fadeIn()` does nothing for visible elements...

```
var balance_update = setInterval(function() {
    $.post('./requests/balance.php', function(balance) {
        $('#balance').html(balance).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
}, 400);
```

Comment: Something else is causing it to not show then.  If you open your console on this page and enter `$("body").hide().fadeIn(1000)` you'll see the page fade in.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of your element needs to be hidden.

Use CSS `{display: none; }` or jQuery's `.hide` method wheb`jQuery(document).ready();` fires

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#balance').html(balance).hide(function(){fadeIn(1000)});
```